# Manually moving labels in rule-based labeling in QGIS 3.10.8

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have a layer with `Name` and `pop_2020` fields. Using the rule-based labeling option, I need to manually move labels for the more fancy-look position. But when I move one label from one field, the other becomes invisible:

before
[image]

after
[image]

Are there any other options except the easy labeling plugin to fix this?

Comment: Be sure to provide a unique ID field, otherwise all labels will be stacked, leading to only one visible label. Easiest to undo the current placement would be reloading the layer.

Comment: Can you clarify, please, what you mean? I have to choose ID field when is the program asking what field I should to choose or what?

Comment: When moving a label manually, you're asked for an ID field. This ID has to be unique, or all labels will be in the same place.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new feature in the QGIS version 3.20 Odense. In the Print Layout when using dynamic, or expression-based labels, users may now select the "Convert to Static Text" option which has been added to the dropdown menu next to "Insert/Edit Expression…", in the layout label properties widget.

This option will evaluate and replace any dynamic parts of a label's contents with their current values. This provides an easy way to convert dynamic labels to static ones, so that users can manually tweak the results when needed.
https://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/3.20/